# EM Wave in Phasor Form

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

[image]

I found this on Google Images:

Does k =(2*pi)/lambda  ???

Also why is E_0 a complex amplitude ?
I would expect E_o to represent a maximum amplitude scalar.

## Edit

[https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters/Complex_Amplitude.html](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/filters/Complex_Amplitude.html)

Do they mean that the entire form is a Complex Amplitude ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter $k = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ is referred to as the wavenumber. In systems with more than one dimension however, what you've described is the *magnitude* of the wave vector $\vec{k}$. The magnitude of $\vec{k}$ is as you've written the wave number $k=|\vec{k}|$, the direction of $\vec{k}$ is the direction of propagation for the wave.

In this representation here the phase of the wave and the amplitude have been collapsed into one variable, the complex amplitude. This is one of the strengths of the phasor representation. Any parameter we can measure from the electric field would be related to $\Re\left(E_0\right)$ and thus the imaginary component is removed, and we're left with a scalar. Another way to look at it would be to realise that all the time-varying components are now in the complex amplitude, what we're left with is a spatial dependence. Perhaps for the material your studying the spatial properties are of more interest and thus the temporal properties are "removed" in this way ?